# how to quickly reverse one-hot enconding?

Tags: python, image, neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I used a neural network to classify an image in python. We need to reverse the one-hot enconding as we want to to display the classified img. The NN has an output of 6 classes that correspond to the level of gray. That's the array of the predictions.

how can we proceed?

Comment: this is the prediction array:[[ True False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False]
 ...
 [ True False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False]]
(257048, 6)

Comment: if you have new information then put it in question - it will be better visible, and more people will see it

Comment: I don't know what you use to create one-hot encoding but usually it should have also function to covnert result back to original values.